# how to add a custom elements into PyMOL visualization?

Tags: pymol, modelling, 3d-structure

I would like to add some 3D elements (balls and lines) to the PyMOL visualization to highlight some "holes" in the structure. Say I `fetch 1tqn` and I want to add a yellow ball somewhere (to specific coordinates, say `[-19, -23, -14]`) in the view. Or a bar from - to coordinates.

[image]

I was going through wiki, did a online search but have not found a way how to add these simple 3D entities into the scene. I guess it should be trivial and I'm just using wrong queries. Because I need to add lots of these, I need to be able to do that via scripting interface.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060582/draw-a-colored-sphere-from-cartesian-coordinates-in-pymol/76749167#76749167 Draw a colored sphere from cartesian coordinates in pymol  and here https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Load_CGO and https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/CGO_Shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my attempt :

```
import pymol

from pymol.cgo import *

from pymol import (
                    
                    cmd ,
                    )


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')


pymol.finish_launching()

cmd.fetch('1tqn')

cmd.remove('solvent')

pos = cmd.get_position()

r = 3

print('###############################################################################\n')

print('### POSITION : ' , pos,'  ###\n')

print('###############################################################################\n')



spherelist = [
    [COLOR,    1.000,    1.000,    0.000,
    SPHERE,   pos[0] , pos[1] , pos[2]  , r ],

    ]

for i in spherelist:
    
    a = str(spherelist.index(i))

    cmd.load_cgo(i, 'sphere_'+a )


cmd.zoom()

cmd.set('cartoon_transparency' , '0.5')
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Aaah, `load_cgo()` https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Load_CGO ("Compiled Graphics Objects"). There are also other shapes: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/CGO_Shapes. Thank you!